# Accssing ASP.NET 5 / MVC6 Identity Custom Profile data properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made a sample web app named ShoppingList using the asp.net 5 web application template (Mvc6/MVC core/Asp.net-5). I wanted to extend the user profile with a custom field name DefaultListId.

The ApplicationUser.cs:

```
namespace ShoppingList.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int DefaultListId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the home controller I would like to access the data stored for this property. I tried:

```
namespace ShoppingList.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           var userId = User.GetUserId();
           ApplicationUser user = userManager.FindById(userId);

            ViewBag.UserId = userId;
            ViewBag.DefaultListId = user.DefaultListId;

            return View();
        }
    //other actions omitted for brevity
```

However I get the following errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the
>   required formal parameter 'optionsAccessor' of
>   'UserManager.UserManager(IUserStore,
>   IOptions, IPasswordHasher,
>   IEnumerable>,
>   IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer,
>   IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider,
>   ILogger>,
>   IHttpContextAccessor)'    ShoppingList.DNX 4.5.1, ShoppingList.DNX Core
>   5.0   C:\Users\OleKristian\Documents\Programmering\ShoppingList\src\ShoppingList\Controllers\HomeController.cs    15  Active

And...

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'UserManager' does not contain a
>   definition for 'FindById' and no extension method 'FindById' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'UserManager' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   ShoppingList.DNX 4.5.1, ShoppingList.DNX Core
>   5.0   C:\Users\OleKristian\Documents\Programmering\ShoppingList\src\ShoppingList\Controllers\HomeController.cs    20  Active

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not instantiate your own `UserManager`, like ever. And it’s actually pretty hard to do so, since it requires you to pass in a lot of arguments to the constructor (and most of those things are also very difficult to set up properly).

ASP.NET Core makes extensive use of dependency injection, so you should just set up your controller in a way that it receives the user manager automatically. That way, you don’t have to worry about creating the user manager:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public HomeController (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    // …
}
```

However, in order to do that, you first need to set up ASP.NET Identity to actually know about your `ApplicationUser` and make it be *used* for storing your user identities. To do that, you need to modify the `Startup` class. In the `ConfigureServices` method, you need to change the `AddIdentity` call to make it reference your actual types:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

`IdentityRole` here refers to the standard role type used by ASP.NET Identity (since you don’t need a custom one). As you can see, we also reference a `ApplicationDbContext` there which is the entity framework database context for your modified identity model; so we need to set up that one too. In your case, it could just look like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        // here you could adjust the mapping
    }
}
```

This will make sure that the `ApplicationUser` entity is actually stored properly in the database. We’re almost done, but we now just need to tell Entity Framework about this database context as well. So again in the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class, make sure to adjust the `AddEntityFramework` call to also set up the `ApplicationDbContext` database context. If you have other database contexts, you can just chain these:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]))
    .AddDbContext<DataContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

And that’s it! Now Entity Framework knows about the new user entity and properly maps it to the database (including your new property), and ASP.NET Identity also knows about your user model and will use that one for everything it does, and you can have the `UserManager` injected into controllers (or services, or whatever) to do stuff.

---

As for your second error, you get this because the user manager does not have a `FindById` method; it only as a `FindByIdAsync` method. You will see this actually in a lot of places with ASP.NET Core that there are only asynchronous methods, so embrace it and start making your method asynchronous as well.

In your case, you would need to change the `Index` method like this:

```
// method is async and returns a Task
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var userId = User.GetUserId();

    // call `FindByIdAsync` and await the result
    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

    ViewBag.UserId = userId;
    ViewBag.DefaultListId = user.DefaultListId;

    return View();
}
```

As you can see, it does not require many changes to make the method asynchronous. Most of it stays just the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a well written and educative answer to my question. I had to make a smaller adjustment to the code, however afterworks it worked like a charm with the existing ApplicationDbContext from the template :  
 services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()
.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]))
.AddDbContext<IdentityDbContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

Comment: @poke..great answer, don't usually see detail like that...What is the best way to store user profile data, that's in the ApplicationUser class, in session. I'm currently using a basecontroller class but that code executes on every action. I should just retrieve it once when they log in and then have some way to access it in each view.

Comment: @dinotom Depending on what kind of information this is, you should consider putting it into claims. That way, they are accessible everywhere without you having to retrieve the user from the database. But sure, you could also use session data for this.

Comment: @poke...yes I am currently trying to figure out exactly how to do that, not getting there though

Comment: @dinotom If you cannot figure it out yourself in the end, feel free to create a new question about it, highlighting what you have learned so far, what attempts you took and how those didn’t work out. Feel free to ping me too, so I can take a look at it then :)